# Probability - Contraception

Tags: probability

With a perfect use of the condom you have a 2% chance to get pregnant each year. These figures seem surprisingly high to me. So I was wondering **what the chance is to have a baby after a lifelong use** (let's assume 25-35 years).

What if you use the pill? And with both the pill & condom? What with the "typical use" scenario?

[Pregnancy chances after one year of use](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_birth_control_methods#Effectiveness_of_various_methods):

- Pill | Perfect use: 0.3%
- Pill | Normal use: 8%
- Condom | Perfect use: 2%
- Condom | Normal use: 15%

Comment: Assuming 30 years, 8.6% chance to have (at least) a baby with pills - perfect use, 92% with pills - normal use (I suppose "normal" means erratic then ;)), 45% with condoms - perfect, and 99% with condoms - normal (again, I think you're quite bad at it if you get 15% chance to get pregnant).

Comment: To begin with, "a 2% chanche to get pregnant each year" seems not really meaningful. One should also specify the number of.... well, "events" per year.

Comment: I suppose the 2% is an average gotten from test results. And @plop, some info on how to get the results would be nice :)

Comment: There is only one way, and it is written right below.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you have a probability of failure for one year of $p$, you have a probability of no failure for one year of $1-p$.  Then the chance of no failure for $n$ years is $(1-p)^n$ if you assume the chances are independent.

Comment: So let me try. The chance of having no baby is 0.997. The chance of not having a baby 30 years in a row is (0.997)^30 or 91.38%? Or a 8.62% of having a baby when taking the pill? Also, how do you calculate it for using both the pill & condom?

Comment: @Carra:  you are right.  For combinations, you need some model for how to combine the probabilities.  You might think the probability is then .02*.003=.06% as both options have to fail together.

Comment: Thanks for the help. Looks like a safe bet with a 0.2% chance after 30 years.